# Pthreads and signals

Tags: c, pthreads, signals

I'm having a little trouble with pthreads.  Basically, I want to catch a SIGINT and have all threads cleanup and exit.  What I have (skeleton code):

main.c:

```
sig_atomic_t running;

void handler(int signal_number)
{
    running = 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    queue job_queue = new_job_queue();

    running = 1;

    struct sigaction sa;
    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
    sa.sa_handler = &handler;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL);

    /* create a bunch of threads */
    init_threads(&job_queue);

    while(running) {
        /* do stuff */
    }

    cleanup();

    return (0);
}
```

threads.c

```
extern sig_atomic_t running;
pthread_mutex_t queue_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
sem_t queue_count;

void init_threads(queue *q)
{
    int numthreads = 12; /* say */

    sem_init (&queue_count, 0, 0);

    pthread_t worker_threads[numthreads];

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<numthreads;i++)
        pthread_create(&worker_threads[i], NULL, &thread_function, q);
}

void * thread_function(void *args)
{
    pthread_detatch(pthread_self());

    queue *q = (queue *)args;

    while(running) {

        job *j = NULL;

        sem_wait(&queue_count);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&queue_mutex);
        j = first_job_in_queue(q);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&queue_mutex);

        if(j) {
            /*do something*/
        }

    }

    return (NULL);
}
```

I am having little luck with this.  Since you're not guarenteed which thread gets the signal I thought this was a good way to go.  But I am having a problem where `sem_wait()` in threads.c is hanging, which is expected but not desired.  The `while(running)` loop in threads.c seems redundant.  Should I maybe do a `pthread_kill()` to all the threads from main?  Any obvious problems with the above skeleton code?  Is there a better/easier way to go about doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to call `sem_post()` from the handler until all threads are unlocked. In the thread function, immediately after `sem_wait()` you should check the value of the `running` variable and if it's zero break breom the while.

The code in the handler could be something like the following:

```
int sval;    
sem_getvalue(&queue_count, &sval);
while (sval < 0) {
    sem_post(&queue_count);
    sem_getvalue(&queue_count, &sval);
}
```

Of course return values should be verified for errors

Comment: +1. This seems like a reasonable approach.  However, I'm not sure that using sem_getvalue is the best plan.  According to the man page, it can place a value of 0 in sval if any threads are waiting on it (that's what it does on the version of Linux I'm using).  It seems it might be better to simply call sem_post the numthreads times to guarantee that all worker threads are released.

Comment: +1 for `sem_post` from signal handlers! This is actually the key property of POSIX semaphores that makes them useful in cases where mutexes and condvars can't do the job: `sem_post` is the **only** pthread synchronization primitive that's async-signal-safe.

Answer (score 1):

You can catch `SIGINT` in one thread, and use `pthread_sigmask()` to block `SIGINT` in all other threads, if `SIGINT` generated by some way, the signal will be delivered to the specified thread, that thread can call `pthread_cancel()` to cancel all other threads.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider calling pthread_join after each call to pthread_create. This will allow for your main thread to wait until all threads are done executing.

But maybe I'm misunderstanding slightly... Do you want to wait for all threads to finish, or simply wait for one to finish, and then stop all others immediately?

Comment: jmoney38: I was actually trying `pthread_join(worker_threads[i], NULL)` in the for loop but it caused the loop to stop after the first one.  I'm not sure what I did.  I guess waiting until the threads have finished is the better way to go.

Comment: Right, so first loop and create, and then loop again and pthread_join on each thread in your array. Yes, it will wait for 0, then 1, then 2... But if a later thread finishes first, it's not a problem, it will just be "skipped". That is to say, there's no error when calling pthread_join on an already-finished thread.

Comment: Ah, so I do the `pthread_create()`'s in the `init_threads()` function and then the `pthread_join()`'s at the end of main (or in the cleanup function as I have it).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do a `pthread_kill()` if you don't have to. I'm not to familiar with `pthread_detatch()` but if you are wanting your `main(`) function to wait for the threads to finish, it would probably be better if your `cleanup()` function did a `pthread_join(`) on each thread id returned from `pthread_create()` to wait for each thread to exit normally.

Also, as far as I can tell, `sem_wait()` is hanging because your semaphore value is initialized to 0. If you want say at most 5 threads to access the shared resource at a time, initialize the semaphore to 5, i.e. `sem_init(&queue_count, 0, 5)`.

Comment: dave-rager:  I'm using a semaphore as well as a mutex because the job queue could become empty.  So I lock the mutex when I take the next job off the queue, but when the queue is empty, the semaphore is there waiting until jobs become available to process again.

Comment: I see. So presumably the while loop in main() is queueing jobs and posting the semaphore?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I should've mentioned that, sorry.